# How to type hint a dict from classes to instances?

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

I've got a dict that maps classes to instances of those classes. How can I type-hint this in Python 3?

```
from typing import Dict
d : Dict[???, ???] = {}

d[int] = 0
d[str] = "hello world"
```

Comment: `Dict[typing.Type, typing.Any]`? I'm not sure you can enforce that the value must be an instance of the key (unless you extend `dict` and override its `__setitem__()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can enforce that the value must be an instance of the key through type hints, but if you're open to extending the `dict` class, you can override its `__setitem__()`:

```
class TypedDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key: Type, value: Any):
        if not isinstance(value, key):
            raise TypeError("TypedDict values must be instances of their keys")
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
```

To use this:

```
>>> td = TypedDict()
>>> td[int] = 0
{int: 0}

>>> td[float] = 1.0
{int: 0, float: 1.0}

>>> td[str] = -1
TypeError: TypedDict values must be instances of their keys
```

Comment: I'm not looking to enforce the types at runtime, I just want to type hint it so that static checkers can catch errors like "d[str] = 42".

Comment: @nullUser right, I'm not sure there's a way you can do that, but I'm not the most experienced with type hints. I hope someone who is will be able to answer though.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `typing.Type` (which refers to the type when using type hints) and `typing.TypeVar` (which allows to link different type places in hints), as follows :

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Type

# We declare a type
T = TypeVar("T")

# T is hint for a value of type T, Type[T] hints for the type T itself. 
def func(data : dict[Type[T], T]) -> int :
    return 1

print(func({int : 1, float: 0.0}))
```

From a purely semantic point of view, I think this is the correct answer, clearly expressing relation between the key type and the value type. It is human-readable and concise, which is good for human-targeted specifications.

**Enforcement issues**

However, changing the last line to (*notice `1.0` after `float:` became `1`*)

```py
print(func({int : 1, float: 1}))
```

Doesn't seem to trigger Pylance in the config I use.

However, testing with last version of MyPy, using [this online env](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12), properly triggers an error :

```
main.py:11: error: Dict entry 1 has incompatible type "type[float]": "int"; expected "type[int]": "int"  [dict-item]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

This error is in my opinion a bit misleading, at it does not mention it could expect `"type[float]": "float"` option, nor gives general info about expected structure.